# Is jquery-mobile able to do div animation or jquery-ui is needed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery-1.6.2 and jquerymobile and I cant do the following simple animation:

```
$('#dtgame').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 600);
```

that gives me the following error:

f.easing[e.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function

so, is it that jquerymobile can't do div animations(page transition already do fine) ?
Do I need to include jquery-ui for this to work?

Thank you,!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems indeed for that code to work we need jqueryui effects code, I headed to jqueryui[1] and download a custom version with only "effects core" and the rest of individual effects and that was enough to apply those effects to animate divs like in my code, my jqueryui custom download was only 27KB so hurray for jqueryui custom download feature!

[1] http://jqueryui.com/download